# How will not affect other table row in onchange in select

Tags: jquery, ajax

I add a first row with a unique id, then I add again for 2nd row.
I change and choose again from the select box, then suddenly it change in the 2nd row even though it is in the 1st row.

How can I fix these problem?

[image]

Here is my code:
[image: Here are my codes.]

Comment: Do not post images of code.  *Post the code*

Comment: Post your code... No one will type it by hand (it is often needed to demonstrate a solution).

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a global variable, so the `success:` function is using the current value of `i`, not the value that it had when you added the event handler. You need to bind a local variable to it.

```
$(document).on("click", "button#add", function() {
    i++;
    let curitem = "#item" + i;
    ...
    $(document).on("change", "#cat" + i, function() {
        var category_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "load_data.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { category_id: category_id },
            success: function(data) {
                $(curitem).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What if in PHP case scenario?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There's no PHP here.